# Use iframe with JQuery Tabs?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, tabs, applet

Im trying to use Jquery tabs with iframes. im calling another HTML which is an applet in the iframe. the first page applet works, afterwards it dont.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#gg1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gg2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="gg1" src="ggapp/eg.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" width="395px" height="470px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <iframe id="gg2" src="ggapp/test2.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" width="395px" height="470px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        panelTemplate: "<iframe style='width:100%'></iframe>",
        idPrefix: "ui-tabs-",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if (!$("#ui-tabs-" + ui.index).prop("src")) {
              $("#ui-tabs-" + ui.index).attr("src", $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs'));  
            } 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you putting your js code under the head tag, just for confirmation. And also are you using lates jquery files ?

Comment: yes to both. i added button on both external html to see if its being called. the button is there just not the applet.